# Emoji aren't displayed correctly in all desktop browsers

Tags: web, unicode, emoji

dear Web developers!

I'm Unity programmer and noob in Web dev. Can you please explain why emojies are not displayed by Google Chrome, but are displayed by Firefox and by Edge - but they looks differently. I know that emojies are Unicode symbols. So browsers can't display Unicode characters?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Displaying Unicode characters visually requires font support. Emojis are a fairly recent addition in Unicode's history, and many web-safe fonts simply don't support Emojis yet, or only support a limited subset of functionality.  Also, Emojis are starting to take advantage of things like Modifiers for providing different representations (colors, skin tones, etc), and that is another newer Unicode feature not widely supported yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice answer!
Please tell me if browsers have built-in fonts or use fonts that present on my Windows?

Comment: both. And fonts can be embedded in web pages, too

Comment: And how do you think, are there any Emojis that will be guaranteed showed in all browsers? may be, the simplest Emojis?

Comment: there is no *guarantee*. You will have to [test them](http://www.fileformat.info/info/emoji/browsertest.htm) and see what happens. Otherwise, use images instead.

Comment: Thank you! Can you transform you comments to answer and I vote it up? (I can't vote up comments unfortunalely)